# Entity Framework search records with a list of strings?

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a database of records that each have a title. I want to be able to search through this database with a search string that will be separated into a list or an array.

So for example if I search with "Book Dog", it will search for all titles that have "Book" or "Dog" in the title.

I'm using entity framework and I guess the simplest way to write down what I want to do is

```
string[] words;
var posts = (from p in ctx.posts
where p.title.contains(words)
select p).ToList();
```

I've tried using a StringExtension I found online, but I would get the following error
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean ContainsAny(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

And the extension is

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string str, params string[] values)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || values.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                if (str.Contains(value))
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
var posts = (from p in ctx.posts
    where words.Any(w => p.title.Contains(w))
    select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you need:

```
ctx.posts.Where(post => words.Any(word => post.Title.Contains(word)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something like your question (Registration form), but my question was: How to find if the **whole name** that I have entered (from text box) is the same **totally** to a record in the database ?

I tried this and worked fine:

```
db.Users.Any(x => x.UserName.Equals(txtUsername.Text))
```

Or for your code like this:

```
ctx.posts.Any(x => x.title.Equals(words))
```

It may be useful for others.